# Efficient Infix alternative to text-overflow?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

There's a [website I frequent and have a casual amount of involvement](https://metacpan.org/recent) with that has to display a table of values like this in a fixed amount of space:

```
Foo-Bar-Baz-1.2.4.6
```

In such a string, the most important parts are not the left-most parts, but the ends.

For instance,

```
Foo-Bar-Baz-Bar-Baz-1.2.4.6
Foo-Bar-Baz-Bar-Quux-1.4.5.5
```

Having these overflowed as:

```
Foo-Bar-Baz-…
Foo-Bar-Baz-…
```

Would be bad, because it hides the most significant parts.

So instead, there's a bit of Javascript in play that calculates the width of the text ( in a proportional width font ) and renders it more like:

```
Foo-…-Baz-1.2.4.6
Foo-…Quux-1.4.5.5
```

```
<td class="name">
  <strong>
    <a href="/release/App-TimeTracker-Command-Category"
       class="ellipsis" 
       title="DOMM/App-TimeTracker-Command-Category-1.001">App-TimeTracker-Command-Category-1.001</a>
   </strong>
</td>
```

```
$.fn.textWidth = function() {
    var html_org = $(this).html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html_calc);
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).html(html_org);
    return width;
};
var items = $('.ellipsis');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var element = $(items[i]);
    var boxWidth = element.width();
    var textWidth = element.textWidth();
    if (textWidth <= boxWidth) continue;
    var text = element.text();
    var textLength = text.length;
    var parts = [text.substr(0, Math.floor(textLength / 2)), text.substr(Math.floor(textLength / 2), textLength)];
    # iteratively elide middle chunks
    # until you kill enough to fit
    while (element.textWidth() > boxWidth) {
        if (textLength % 2) {
            parts[0] = parts[0].substr(0, parts[0].length - 1);
        } else {
            parts[1] = parts[1].substr(1, parts[1].length);
        }
        textLength--;
        element.html(parts.join('…'));
    }
}
```

The downside is this is incredibly slow, with each call to `.textWidth()` triggering **both** a CSS refresh **and** a layout reflow, and so this simple loop can easily account for 85% of all page CPU activity during load.

[image: Operas Chromium Webkit based performance graph]

Here you see those little red and violet flecks being the browser going crazy parsing HTML, applying CSS and reflowing the page over and over again.

The downside is the only place this work *can* be done is client side, because the ability to know whether a fold is required or not, ( and where an appropriate and optimal fold location is ) depends significantly on the display devices font rendering dynamics, due to the glory of proportional width fonts.

I would have loved to use CSS3 `text-overflow:` here, but as stated earlier, it gives the undesirable side effect of hiding the most important data.

(I'm considering seeing if the "find a break" can be done with binary search, but I'm not confident that it will solve the lions share of the performance problem)

Comment: Here's an idea... split the string with the suffix and measure it. Split each letters and measure each letters individually into `span` with the same styles. Then just add all letters you need until you reach a max size. You'll have to calculate once the size of each letters so for "Bar-Bar" you have only `4` DOM events. As you don't have to calculate every letters multiple times.

Comment: Measuring the width of each letter would cause *more* calls to .textWidth, and that's where the primary bottleneck is.

Comment: Hm, I guess it does mean you max out at a total of 64 calls, I'm just not sure if that's cumulatively better or worse than what presently happens. Will have to check.

Comment: I wouldn't even have to call `textWidth`, You measure each letters once and then you sum up the letters that you want without having to measure it each time.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I'm temporarily paranoid about the potential for ligatures to mess things up, but I expect what we're doing we might never see those.

Comment: Even ligatures are recognized as one symbol as far as I know. Œ for example. The only thing that could mess up is letter spacing between two letters.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix "You measure each letters once" measure the letters *how*? You'd still have to have the letters somewhere, in isolation order to measure them. Unless there's a "get the display width of a character" function I've not heard of.

Comment: You'd have to measure symbols individually like you do in `textWidth` and save the width of each symbol. It would work if your space doesn't have some kind of `margin` that add up more space between letters.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I mean Unicode Ligatures, there are characters in Unicode that have spacing subject to the characters beside them.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that could happen. Though using your algo, you could reduce the amount of steps to find the right width using an algo that is similar to dichotomic search...ah no that wouldn't work if you want the same amount of letters in head and tail

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I managed to glue up a "calculate the letter widths" solution, but then I realised Unicode exists, and I could potentially have a mallicious user create a Unicode string with every possible unicode character. 109 thousand DOM Reflows might hurt a little.